# How to match a column and its crawled property?

Tags: 2013, refiner, crawled-property

We are using SharePoint 2013 on-premise. I have a managed metadata column `Wiki Categories`. After reset index and full crawl, I found several fields have the name `wiki`. I marked them as `refinable` and full crawl again. However none of them can refine anything when setup in the search page refiner.

My question is, how can I match a column and its crawled property beside guess through their "naming"?

Answer (score 1):

When search performs full crawl, it generates a crawled property for each of the managed metadata columns. Crawled property for site columns are always prefixed with `ows_` and the spaces in site column name are encoded as `_x0020_`.

So in your case it will be `ows_Wiki_x0020_Categories` (Provided this name doesn't exists)

To use this as a refiner, you need to associate this property with a managed property. For that you can either create a new Managed Property or use an existing one (`RefinableString00 - RefinableString99`). Remember to mark each of these managed properties as - `Queryable`, `Retrievable` and `Refinable`.

Now you can edit the `Search Refinement` properties and add the new `Refiner` you created above.

Comment: In the search schema page, I searched with "wiki" keyword and get following crawled properties: ows_r_MTXT_WikiField
ows_taxId_Wiki_x0020_Page_x0020_Categories, ows_Wiki_x0020_Page_x0020_Categories, ows_WikiField, 
ows_wikipage. I tested the first 3 and none of them return expected refine results. I need to full crawl again and again during test. My question is, I need to repeatly full crawl and blind guess the matching property?